# «Você quer que eu te ligue?» é gramatical?

Tags: gramática

Após uma discussão no meta, [Da absurdidade de um limite mínimo para edição de uma pergunta](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/274/153), ficou a dúvida se a frase seguinte é gramatical:

> Você quer que eu te ligue? / Vocês querem que eu vos ligue?

ou deveria ser

> Você quer que eu lhe ligue? / Vocês querem que eu lhes ligue?

Ou ambas são gramaticais? Podem ter o mesmo significado?

Em Portugal poderia usar-se «Você quer que eu lhe ligue?» num sentido mais formal, numa conversa com um professor ou um superior hierárquico.

Comment: É do tipo «vocês querem que eu vos ligue» que nós dizemos em Portugal.

Comment: @Jacinto imagina que eu estou a falar para o meu chefe, «Você quer que eu lhe ligue amanhã?»

Comment: «Você que que eu lhe ligue» é gramaticalíssimo, e é a única coisa que se ouve em Portugal. «Você quer que eu te ligue» viola a concordância canónica, mas creio que é frequente no Brasil. Do ponto de vista da forma, é análogo ao «vocês querem que eu vos ligue» corrente em Portugal. Agora enquanto *vocês* com *vos* é aceite em Portugal mesmo no registo forml, não sei se *você* com *te* tem aceitação igualmente generalizada no Brasil.

Comment: @Jacinto era isso que eu queria descobrir.

Comment: Talvez valesse a pena precisares isso na pergunta. Do ponto de vista da gramática clássica, «você quer que eu te ligue» e «vocês querem que eu vos ligue» são igualmente incorretos; a analogia entre os dois é perfeita.

Comment: @Jacinto agora confundiste-me, «vocês querem que eu vos ligue» eu uso as vezes...

Comment: Numa busca no google praticamente não encontrei "você quer que eu lhe ligue", sendo comum  "você quer que eu te ligue" ou "você quer que eu ligue"

Comment: @Jacinto porque razão está incorrecto o «vocês querem que eu vos ligue»? Não há concordância??

Comment: @Anold Sim, de acordo com a gramática clássica, *vos* é para *vós*: «vós quereis que eu vos ligue»; no tratamento por *você* deveria ser «vocês querem que eu lhes ligue»; mas em Portugal a grande maioria mistura: «vocês querem que eu vos ligue». Jorge, tu falas assim às vezes!? Eu falo assim sempre; se disser «lhes ligue», parece-me que estou a falar de ligar a terceiros e não a vocês. Nós reparamos no «você quer que eu te ligue» dos brasileiros porque nunca misturamos no singular; e como no plural misturamos tanto, já nem reparamos; não misturar é que já soa estranho.

Comment: @Jacinto mas o vós não é para o plural, ainda que as pessoas o usem para o singular, quando se trata de alguém que devemos 'honrar' ?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Mesmo com o *vós* honorífico, dirias «vós quereis que vos ligue», nunca «vocês...»

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depende de a quem perguntares, mas cada vez mais «você quer que eu te ligue» é aceite no Brasil, tal como «vocês querem que eu vos ligue» o é em Portugal.

Com pronomes de tratamento — *você, vossa mercê, vossa excelência, vossa majestade*, etc. — a gramática tradicional prescreve a concordância na terceira pessoa. Isto vem dos tempos em que perante um interlocutor importante, por uma questão de respeito, em vez de falares diretamente dele, falavas de algum aspeto dele: a majestade dele, a excelência dele ou a mercê dele. Logo, é como estares a falar de uma terceira entidade, e utilizas portanto a terceira pessoa — era como se estivesses a falar da esposa dele. Compara:

> **Tu queres** que eu **te** ligue?
>   **Vossa esposa quer** que eu **lhe** ligue?
>   **Vossa mercê quer** que eu **lhe** ligue?

E do mesmo modo no plural:

> **Vós quereis** que eu **vos** ligue?
>   **Vossas esposas querem** que eu **lhes** ligue?
>   **Vossas mercês querem** que eu **lhes** ligue?

Entretanto *vossa mercê* passou a *vossemecê* e *vosmecê* e a *você*, mas a concordância foi-se mantendo na terceira pessoa. Só que mais recentemente aconteceram uns desenvolvimentos interessantes. Com *você*, o pessoal manteve a conjugação verbal na terceira pessoa, mas começou a usar pronomes oblíquos e possessivos da segunda pessoa. No Brasil isto aconteceu no singular; em Portugal, apenas no plural:

> Brasil: **você quer** que eu **te** ligue?
>   Portugal: **vocês querem** que eu **vos** ligue?

Portugal mantém a concordância tradicional no singular (*você* é sempre com *lhe*; o *te*, só com *tu*). No Brasil no plural, tende-se a evitar o pronome oblíquo com a locução *para você* (ver a outra resposta), mas eu também encontrei a concordância tradicional no Google (*vocês* com *lhes*).

O que não faltam por aí são pedagogos a condenar a mistura de *você* e *vocês* com pronomes da segunda pessoa. Veja-se este [artigo no Gramaticalhas (2004)](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI7505,101048-Uniformidade+de+tratamento), mais a propósito da situação brasileira; e [este no Ciberdúvidas (1998)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vos--lhes/2834) a propósito de Portugal, que diz:

> Não podemos fazer misturas do género «estou aqui para **vos** dizer o que **vocês** não **sabem**»

Continua que deve ser «para **vos** dizer o que **vós** não **sabeis**» ou «para **lhes** dizer o que **vocês** não **sabem**». Mas em Portugal ninguém quer saber deste conselho; nem mesmo o Presidente da República, que é professor catedrático da Universidade de Lisboa. Ei-lo aqui num [discurso no Congresso dos Revisores de Contas (2016)](http://www.presidencia.pt/?idc=37&idi=114457). Notem o verbo na terceira pessoa, que tem implícito um pronome de tratamento:

> E por falar na nossa economia, **deixem** que **vos** enuncie três pistas de reflexão

Eu diria que em Portugal *vocês* vem maioritariamente com *vos*, ao ponto de algumas pessoas se interrogarem se *lhes* é correto (consulente do [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vos--lhes/2834)). Os colegas brasileiros dizem que no Brasil *você* vem também maioritariamente com *te*, e [neste artigo de *Sua Língua*](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/13/lhe-te-e-voce/) uma consulente interroga-se igualmente se *lhe* pode ser usado com *você*.

Answer (score 6):

O significado de ambas é o mesmo. Em rigor, apenas a concordância da 2ª está correta ("Você quer que eu lhe ligue?"), mas na maior parte do Brasil você nunca ouvirá essa concordância.

No português brasileiro, embora o "tu" seja pouco usado (apenas em algumas regiões e, muitas vezes, concordando com o verbo na 3ª pessoa), o pronome "te" com referência a "você" é bastante comum (muito mais comum que "lhe").

"Você quer que eu te ligue?" é a maneira como a grande maioria dos brasileiros faria essa pergunta, mesmo em registros mais formais.

Quanto ao "vos", nunca será ouvido no Brasil. O plural da pergunta seria invariavelmente "Vocês querem que eu ligue pra vocês?".

Comment: Interessante. Não tinha essa ideia, que *você* com *te* fosse no Brasil já quase universal.

Comment: @Jacinto Não sei se eu diria universal, pois há variações regionais, mas sem dúvida *você* + *te* é dominante e amplamente aceito no Brasil.

Comment: Eu evito  misturar a 2ª e 3ª pessoas.  Eu diria:  "quer que eu ligue pra você?"

Comment: No Congresso Nacional e no Judiciário é possível ouvirmos "vós", "vossa", "vos", etc, embora a hipocrisia esteja frequentemente por trás desse uso.

Comment: Como assim @Centaurus?

Comment: @JorgeB.   A hipocrisia?   É porque nossos congressistas usam pronomes formais até quando a discussão está em clima quente ou estão xingando uns aos outros  ("vossa excelência não sabe o que diz", "vossa excelência é um mentecapto!)  Tudo para disfarçar a vulgaridade e passar a falsa imagem de que são diferentes do "povão".

Answer (score 2):

Depende do que você quer dizer por "gramatical". Se quer dizer, "de acordo com a gramática padrão, ensinada nas escolas e nos livros", então "*Você quer que eu te ligue?*" é agramatical. O correto é "*Você* (ou *O senhor*) *quer que eu lhe ligue?*".

Se por "gramatical" você quer dizer, "de acordo com regras gramaticais, escritas ou não, independente de status social, etc.", então a frase é gramatical **no português coloquial do Brasil**.

Não é o caso de "*Vocês querem que eu vos ligue?*", que - no Brasil pelo menos - é completamente agramatical. No padrão, "vocês" tem de concordar com "lhes", jamais com "vos". No coloquial, "vos" não existe (e desconfio que não existe no padrão também, sendo restrita ao registro literário).

Quanto a "*Você quer que eu lhe ligue?*" e "*Vocês querem que eu lhes ligue?*", ambas são gramaticais (e a forma preferível) no português padrão do Brasil. No coloquial, ambas são, creio, aceitáveis no limite mas quase insuportavelmente pedantes. Diríamos antes, "*Você quer que eu ligue?*" e "*Vocês querem que eu ligue?*", "*Você quer que eu te ligue?*", "*Você quer que eu ligue pra você?*", "*Vocês querem que eu ligue pra vocês?*", "*Ligo pra você(s)?*". Ou, ao telefone, "*Você quer que eu ligue de volta?*".