# Licença poética e o paralelismo

Tags: pronomes, interpretação

Ao escrever um texto, é muito comum utilizarmos um paralelismo nos pronomes. Ou seja, se tratarmos — com o pronome *tu* — determinada pessoa, então é comum que utilizemos os pronomes: *te*, *ti*, *teu(s)* e *tua(s)*. Por exemplo:

> **Deixa**-me ser a **tua** amiga, Amor,
> A **tua** amiga só, já que não **queres**
> Que pelo **teu** amor seja a melhor,
> A mais triste de todas as mulheres.
>
> Que só, de **ti**, me venha mágoa e dor
> O que me importa a mim?! O que **quiseres**
> É sempre um sonho bom! Seja o que for,
> Bendito **sejas** **tu** por mo dizeres!
> (...)
>
> — Florbela Espanca

Como podem observar, toda vez que Florbela refere-se a alguém, ela usa um paralelismo, sempre usa o pronome *tu*. Porém, num poema de Machado¹, podemos ler uma mistura entre os pronomes da segunda e terceira pessoa.

> Por que sinto falta de **você**? Por que está saudade?
> Eu não *t̲e̲* vejo mas imagino **suas** expressões, **sua** voz *t̲e̲u̲* cheiro.
> **Sua** amizade me faz sonhar com um carinho,
> Um caminhar, a luz da lua, a beira-mar.
> Saudade este sentimento de vazio que me tira o sono, 
> me fazendo sentir num triste abandono, é amizade eu sei, será amor talvez...
> Só não quero perder **sua** amizade, esta amizade...
> Que me fortalece me enobrece por ter **você**.
>
> — Machado¹

**Seguem minhas dúvidas:**

**1)** Visto que a norma culta *proíbe* essas variações, podemos concluir que o autor do poema utilizou a licença poética?
**2)** Os pronomes *te*, *teu*, *sua* e *você*, no poema, referem-se à mesma pessoa?

---

<sub>Nota 1: Há pessoas que afirmam que o poema *Saudade* é de Machado de Assis (1839 — 1908); outros, porém, dizem ser de Alcântara Machado (1901 — 1935).</sub>

Comment: P.S.: Em alguns textos, o *esta* (primeira linha) é descrito como verbo → *Por que **está** saudade?*

Comment: Ver pergunta sobre [***você*** com ***te***](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/voc%c3%aa-quer-que-eu-te-ligue-%c3%a9-gramatical) e outra sobre [***vocês*** com ***vosso***](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/%c3%89-correto-usar-voc%c3%aas-em-vez-de-v%c3%b3s/1766#1766)

Comment: Quando à pergunta 1), a norma culta é estabelecida pelo uso e não regulada por entidade nenhuma, de modo que não me parece possível ir além das perguntas que linkei. Quando à 2), não há nada no poema que permita relacionar os pronomes com pessoas/entidade diferentes. Também não me parece possível dizer nada de objetivo além disto.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [«Você quer que eu te ligue?» é gramatical?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/voc%c3%aa-quer-que-eu-te-ligue-%c3%a9-gramatical)

Comment: @toliveira A pergunta *linkada* não responde completamente a minha, de modo que não vejo o porquê ser duplicada.

Comment: @Jacinto Compartilho da mesma opinião quanto à resposta 2. Ao ver seria licença poética e por isso não faria sentido referenciar outras pessoas do texto, apenas queria uma elucidação. 1) As respostas são boas, uma pena que a maioria delas foquem apenas na língua coloquial/falada. No Brasil, há um [decreto](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_Ato2007-2010/2008/Decreto/D6583.htm) que "regulamenta" as novas regras da língua escrita.

Comment: De acordo [Arnaldo Niskier](http://www.academia.org.br/artigos/lingua-sem-extremismos), *“Concordamos com os linguistas que ninguém erra ao falar e sim transgride as determinações da norma culta, o que é perfeitamente aceitável na linguagem coloquial. Entretanto, no que se relaciona à escrita, há erro e não transgressão, o que não devemos admitir. O Vocábulo açúcar por exemplo, deve ser grafado com ç e acento e jamais ser aceito com dois s, o que não mudaria o som mas a etimologia da palavra.”*

Comment: Valdeir, o decreto que referes regula apenas a ortografia.A resposta do Luís Henrique à pergunta linkada já faz a distinção entre coloquial, o prescrito em gramáticas, etc. Mas se achas que isso não é suficiente, o que eu faria era precisar na tua pergunta exatamente o que é queres ver explicado que ainda não está respondido na outra pergunta. Nomeadamente, precisar o que é a norma culta. Se não é o que vem nas gramáticas, é o quê. Por outro lado, ocorreu-me agora, que se tratas alguém por *você*, a comunicação não será muito formal, certo?

Comment: @Jacinto Concordo com a resposta do Luís Henrique, por isso deixei claro que a maioria (e não todas) focam apenas na língua falada. O decreto supramencionado é um bom indício que a língua é "regulamenta", que há regras. O *você*, nos dias atuais, é, de fato, bastante informal. Porém este fato pode está ligado ao [estilo do poeta](https://infomodernismo.wixsite.com/muiraquita/analise-poema-saudade) ou licença poética.

Comment: Qualquer português ficaria cheio de comichão ao ler esse poema... a falta de paralelismo é dissonante para os portugueses.

Comment: No poema do Machado, ele usa **você** (eu///tu///você, ele, ela) e ele usa sua (minha///tua///**sua**. Não mistura nada.  Ou seja, ele usa só a terceira pessoa do singular. A mistura sería usar você com o tu. Credo. Como é possível que ninguém falou nisso??

Answer (score 1):

Eu entendo que não se trata de licença poética. É muito comum na linguagem informal em português o uso do "teu" "te" em conjunto com o "você", particularmente nos estados do sul e sudeste (Paraná, Santa Catarina e Rio Grande do Sul). O uso de simultãneo de seu/teu na mesma frase também é  comum, e em muitos casos não é somente uma marca de informalidade, mas sim um erro de português mesmo, já que a maioria das pessoas pouco sabe sobre as conjugações e pronomes da segunda pessoa do singular. São coisas que se aprende na escola, e depois raramente se usa.

Assim, na linguagem informa falada, diz-se:

> -Você sabe que se teu filho for mal na escola, a culpa é tua!

ou ainda:

> -Você sabe que se teu filho for mal na escola, a culpa é sua!

O uso do pronome "tu" é quase que exclusivo dos estados do extremo Sul do Brasil, Rio Grande do Sul e Santa Catarina. A frase abaixo certamente só seria falada por um morador do extremo sul do Brasil.

> -Tu sabes, que se teu filho for mal na escola, a culpa é tua!

Já o uso dos pronomes "teu", "tua" é utilizado mais livremente, mesmo para o pronome "Você", quando da linguagem falada ou informa.

Comment: Mas será que a alternação entre "seu" e "teu", na mesma frase, como no poema, é comum no português do Brasil? O exemplo que você deu usa somente "teu" e "tua" com "você".

Comment: @DanGetz, acho que "teu" é mais informal e forte do que "seu", porém, claro que pode; ex.: "a tu' idei' é ruim, mas, pelo menos, a su' intenção foi boa". Hoje, eu tento me manter num só pronome, então, resolvi falar apenas "tu" e "vós", em vez de "você" e "vocês". Assim, eu sou uma grandíssima exceção, mas, antes d'eu decidir falar "tu" e "vós", era muito comum eu misturar "seu" e "teu", principalmente por raiva ou por querer ser informal com alguém; ex.: "cala a tua boca ou eu jogo (o) seu celular no rio!".

Comment: @DanGetz, disse isso porque a minha observação pode estar comprometida, já que já estou quase me acostumado a "tu" e "vós".

Comment: @Schilive obrigado, faz sentido. Acho que a tua explicação pode servir como resposta a "1" e "2" na pergunta original.

Comment: @DanGetz, pode se usar apenas como um complemento para uma resposta, porque eu estava me referindo apenas à língua falada.

Comment: @Schilive "(1) podemos concluir que é licença poética? não, porque **existe na lingua falada**"... e para (2) parece-me que tens um bom motivo para a possibilidade de "sim" nos teus exemplos

Comment: @DanGetz, só porque existe na língua falada, não quer dizer que não é licença poética. Quero dizer que, em uma resposta, explicaria muito mais as coisas. Aqui, só respondi a um dos pontos. Mas realmente pode servir de base para uma resposta.

Comment: @DanGetz sim é comum o uso de seu e teu na mesma frase. Adicionei esta opção na resposta. Tenha em mente que a conjugação dos verbos e até mesmo o uso correto dos pronomes da segunda pessoa do singular não são de conhecimento geral da população; é algo que acaba sendo usado mais em textos acadêmicos ou linguagem de advocacia.