# Se eu eu falar "vós", serei entendido?

Tags: pronomes, conjugações

Eu nasci no Brasil, SP, SBC. Aqui, não se fala "vós"; digo, não é algo regional.

Porém, eu amo a conjugação e as desinências: *convosco*, *sois*, *estais*. Também adoro as conjugações com acento, "estáveis", e o imperativo, "fazei", "matai-o!".

Eu fiz um teste no Omegle, um site em que se conversa com estranhos aleatórios, perguntando se entendiam e se achavam chato o uso de "vós". Eu acabei perguntando para 17 pessoas, 16 disseram que entendiam perfeitamente e não achavam chato; boa parte, na realidade, disse que não achava nem chato nem legal, como se não importassem. 1 estava neutro, porque não se importava.

Após isso, eu comecei a pensar se, se eu não soubesse a conjugação, eu entenderia. Cheguei à conclusão que sim, talvez não entendesse "para fazerdes", mas entenderia por eliminação e contexto, sem muito esforço -- muitas pessoas falam "para vocês ir", então, fica fácil.

Tendo tais informações em mente, as pessoas realmente me entenderiam se eu falar "vós" em vez de vocês"? Nas situações que o usei, fui entendido, mas isso não diz rem.

P.S.: eu uso "tu", mas as pessoas o entendem tranqüilamente.

A quem disser que é uma pergunta opinativa: não digo que estás errado, mas que eu apresentei observações, podendo quem responder usar próprias observações, e estou pedindo a alguém por uma conclusão lógica, já que não me julgo competente de concluir -- afinal, eu vou sempre tender para um certo lado. Eu não gostaria duma resposta "sim" ou "não", mas aceitarei a melhor.

Comment: Eu acho que a maioria entenderia porque essas palavras, apesar de não serem de uso frequente na língua falada, são ensinadas nas escolas. Além disso, são comuns na Bíblia e nas orações de modo que boa parte das pessoas deve estar habituada com elas.

Comment: @Pedro, não posso votar por algum motivo, mas eu não tinha pensado na Bíblia.

Comment: Marius, não podias votar porque ainda não tinhas chegado a reputação 15; agora já deves poder. Não compreendo é qual é exatamente a pergunta. Porque poder usar o tratamento por *vós*, é claro que podes; ninguém te impede. Eu uso por vezes, na brincadeira. No norte de Portugal ainda há quem use; vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/qual-%c3%a9-a-etiqueta-no-uso-de-v%c3%b3s-podeis-v%c3%b3s-sabeis-etc-no-norte-de-portugal) e links que já há.

Comment: E em todo o Portugal é muito comum usar *vosso, vos* no tratamento por *vocês*, paralelo ao uso de *teu, te* com *você* no Brasil. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/voc%c3%aa-quer-que-eu-te-ligue-%c3%a9-gramatical) e também [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/%c3%89-correto-usar-voc%c3%aas-em-vez-de-v%c3%b3s?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Em português brasileiro o uso de pronomes de segunda pessoa é desencorajado por diversas gramáticas, como toda escola ensina esses pronomes, ninguém terá dificuldade em entendê-los. São formas provindas do latim, que permaneceram na gramática normativa. Até mesmo formas como Vossa Excelência ou Vossa Senhoria devem concordar com a segunda pessoa: Vossa Excelência está atarefado (vide: http://www4.planalto.gov.br/centrodeestudos/assuntos/manual-de-redacao-da-presidencia-da-republica/manual-de-redacao.pdf).

Comment: @Edney, o que eu não entendo é que parece que as gramáticas geralmente têm mais problemas com "vós" do que os próprios lusófonos. Eu não sei o porquê.

Comment: No Brasil é raro o uso de "vós" e "tú", mas no Sul se fala tú até mesmo no dia a dia. Penso que isso foi mantido para haver compatibilidade gramatical entre países lusófonos, mas não sei afirmar com certeza. O português como língua natural e não língua sintética, tem vários detalhes e exceções à regra que talvez a resposta para isso seja: é assim, por que é assim... ninguém se mobilizou para realizar essa alteração, ainda mais por quê seria bem difícil mudar o jeito de falar de uma população tão numerosa.

Comment: Embora exista o aspecto de convergência evolutiva a especificação geográfica torna o português falado pelo mundo afora cada vez mais diferente (entre populações), ainda que com a internet haja maior intercâmbio, ainda existe certo distanciamento cultural.

Answer (score 1):

Eu creio que te vão entender. Posso dizer isto apenas muito tentativamente no caso do Brasil; com confiança no caso de Portugal, onde nasci e cresci. E a razão é esta: no meio em que eu cresci, como na maior parte de Portugal, não se conjugam verbos na segunda pessoa do plural: diz-se *vocês/os senhores estão, vão*, não *vós estais, ides*. Nem tenho qualquer memória de ter aprendido estas conjugações na escola. No entanto eu compreendo-as.

Já várias vezes me perguntei como é que as aprendi. Creio que na igreja, que eu frequentava dominicalmente na minha infância, o padre usava estas conjugações. Pelo menos são elas que aparecem no *Pai Nosso* que eu conheço: “Pai nosso que **estais** nos céus […] **perdoai** as nossas ofensas […]”; também na “Ave Maria […] **rogai** por nós […]”.  Também é possível que tenha encontrado estas conjugações em obras de ficção logo que comecei a ler: nalgumas histórias passadas em tempos antigos, as personagens tratam-se por vós. E na escola secundária lemos alguma literatura antiga — poesia medieval, crónicas do século XV, Camões— em que há o tratamento por vós.

Não me lembro de em qualquer momento não ter compreendido estas conjugações. E como a minha exposição a elas foi sempre passiva (ouvinte ou leitor, nunca falante) e muito limitada, estou em crer que as compreendi simplesmente pelo contexto, e que provavelmente qualquer falante nativo do português as compreenderá também.

A propósito de obras de ficção, ainda ontem por coincidência, vi na TV *The Princess Bride*, e nas legendas (em Portugal, séries e filmes estrangeiros, exceto infantis, são legendados) algumas personagens tratam-se por vós — para se dirigirem a várias pessoas, e também em vez do *tu* para se dirigirem respeitosamente a uma só, como no *Pai Nosso* e *Ave Maria*. É o mesmo n’*Os Tudors*, a passar neste momento em Portugal, e também n’*A Guerra do Tronos*, que passou há pouco tempo. (E depois tens personagens como o Hound a dizer a um companheiro coisas como, *ide f***r-vos*, tudo muito respeitosamente!). Isto são apenas três entre as dúzias de filmes e séries que podes ver na TV por cabo em Portugal, mas mostra que quem tratou das legendagens partiu do princípio que o público iria compreender.

Há um caso especial, o norte de Portugal, onde algumas pessoas ainda usam cotidianamente o tratamento por vós. A minha impressão é que são uma minoria, mas mesmo quem não usa estará relativamente familiarizado. Vê os testemunhos pessoais na resposta e comentários a [esta pergunta sobre a etiqueta no tratamento por *vós* no norte de Portugal](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/qual-%C3%A9-a-etiqueta-no-uso-de-v%C3%B3s-podeis-v%C3%B3s-sabeis-etc-no-norte-de-portugal).

### Pronomes *vos* e *vosso, vossa*, etc.

Ao contrário das conjugações verbais da segunda pessoa do plural, os pronomes *vos, vosso, vossa*, etc. são usados por todo o Portugal, porque são usados com os pronomes de tratamento no plural. Por exemplo:

> Vocês/os senhores esperem aqui, que eu já **vos** mostro os **vosso** lugares

Há puristas que insistem que com *você*/*os senhores* deve ser *já **lhes** mostro os **seus** lugares*, mas esta mistura de tratamentos (só no plural) é aceite até mesmo em linguagem relativamente formal. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/voc%C3%AA-quer-que-eu-te-ligue-%C3%A9-gramatical) e mais [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/%C3%89-correto-usar-voc%C3%AAs-em-vez-de-v%C3%B3s?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: No Brasil, acho que também entenderão. Até porque "vós" é bem regular. Principalmente se souber o motivo da coexistência de "-des" e "-eis"; ex.: "fazeis, mas não era para fazerdes!". "matades" > "mata-es" hiato > "mataes" ditongo > "matais", pelo que sei, apenas aconteceu em "-d-" intervocálico (entre vogais), então, "tendes" não se tornou "teneis" ou "te~eis".