# Qual é mais adequado: "vossa instituição" ou "sua instituição"?

Tags: pronomes, concordância, colocação-pronominal

A palavra "vossa" é um pronome de tratamento muito empregada no Brasil como vocativo.

> Exemplos: Vossa Excelência, Vossa Senhoria, Vossa Eminência, etc

Mas para determinar coisa não é muito comum. Sendo assim, qual a opção mais correta dos exemplos abaixo:

> 1 - Me coloco à disposição para conversar e explicar melhor sobre
> minha experiência e como posso contribuir com **sua** instituição de ensino.

Ou

> 2 - Me coloco à disposição para conversar e explicar melhor sobre
> minha experiência e como posso contribuir com **vossa** instituição de ensino.

Nesse exemplo é melhor usar "vossa instituição" ou "sua instituição"?

Como seria no Brasil, em Portugal ou em outros países falantes da língua portuguesa?

Comment: De acordo com https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf46.php, os pronomes de tratamento devem ser tratados na terceira pessoa, ou seja, como se fossem um substantivo, assim como “você sabe o seu” e não “você sabe o vosso”. Pelo que já ouvi, é comum em Portugal usar-se “vosso” quando falando com uma ou mais pessoas para mostrar-lhe respeito. Esse segundo foi usado na novela Novo Mundo da Globo. Já também ouvi “vos”, como em “eu vos disse” ou “eu disse a vós ontem, Imperador”, sendo usado para uma pessoa só, mostrando respeito, mas não vou afirmar 100% este aqui.

Comment: Queres dizer mesmo "contribuir com sua/vossa instituição"? Eu digo *contribuir para*.

Comment: Sim, o mais natural para mim é "contribuir com a sua instituição", pois instituição no caso é uma empresa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Portugal é mais natural *vossa* do que *sua*; no Brasil, como já diz, o Stafusa, o natural é *sua*. Vejamos. ***Vossa*** é possessivo de *vós*:

> **Vós sois** uma inspiração para mim. Adoraria trabalhar na **vossa** instituição.

Ora este tratamento por *vós* basicamente caiu em desuso. Ainda será usado no dia a dia por alguns falantes no norte de Portugal e em algumas ocasiões muito solenes: alguns sacerdotes usam-no nos serviços religiosos. De resto o *vós* foi substituído por pronomes de tratamento como *vocês* ou *os senhores*, que gramaticalmente são da terceira pessoa:

> **Os Senhores são** uma inspiração para mim. Adoraria trabalhar na **sua** instituição.

E no Brasil é isto. Em Portugal é mais complicado. Tal como no Brasil se mistura *você* com *teu*, em Portugal mistura-se *vocês* e *o senhor* com *vosso*. E esta mistura está generalizada e é aceite (exceto por uma minoria em vias de extinção) mesmo em ocasiões formais (vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/voc%C3%AA-quer-que-eu-te-ligue-%C3%A9-gramatical)). Em Portugal o exemplo abaixo soa bem mais natural do que soaria com *sua* em vez de *vossa*:

> **Os Senhores são** uma inspiração para mim. Adoraria trabalhar na **vossa** instituição.

Dei uma vista de olhos pela net, e também se faz esta mistura (notem o verbo na terceira pessoa) em Angola (“Senhores empresários e empreendedores, ocupem os vossos espaços”, [Jornal e Angola, 2019)](https://jornaldeangola.ao/ao/noticias/detalhes.php?id=433200), em Moçambique (“imagino a vossa frustração quando estão perante um paciente”, [Associação Médica de Moçambique, 2015)](https://www.associacaomedica.org.mz/mensagem-do-presidente-da-republica-alusiva-ao-dia-do-medico-mocambicano/) e em Cabo Verde (“agradecemos a vossa presença. Sintam-se, pois, em casa”, [Tarrafal, 2021](https://cmt.cv/index.php/expediente/79-slideshow/582-sessao-solene-do-dia-do-municipio-discurso-do-presidente-da-camara-municipal).

Quanto ao *Vossa Excelência*, isso é uma fórmula cristalizada vinda dos tempos em que se usava *vós*. Tanto para te dirigires a várias pessoas, como para te dirigires respeitosamente a uma pessoa só (*D. Pedro, vós sois uma inspiração para mim*), daí ser *Vossa Excelência* e não *Tua Excelência*.

Answer (score 0):

No Brasil, "*sua* instituição" seria, de longe, o mais usual.

Na minha experiência, o uso mais provável de "vossa instituição, por um falante nativo de pt-BR, seria jocosamente, sugerindo uma formalidade empolada.